# Overlapping image on profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page

So, I was checking this user's profile

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868647/ker-jen

In which the user added an image in place of bio. But, that image is overlapped 50% of his profile picture. Like below

in Firefox 62.0 (64-bit)

[image]

in Google Chrome 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

And I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (x64)

This looks weird I'm not sure whether it's due to image resolution or bug in styling the page.