# Walls of text distort user profiles

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

I've been noticing this with a few user profiles of late. A large amount of About Me text can cause the user's profile to be distorted. Here is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639671/flutefreak7

[image]

The user's display picture, badges and reputation are hidden by the container holding the About Me text.

This is the second time I've noticed this, and I was able to reproduce this on both Safari (v12) and Chrome (v69).

Comment: We've got another couple bugs that are clipping or entirely removing the user's icon: [Overlapping image on profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374711/7795130) and [The profile page is scrambled when using a wide image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374682/7795130), but those were both thought to be fault of the image being included. By your report, looks like text is causing the same issue.

Comment: This is due to the recent changes in favour of flexbox.. Class `.fl1` needs to be `flex: 1 0 !important;` instead of `flex: 1 auto !important;` to prevent shrinking.

Comment: still not fixed : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled-when-using-a-wide-image?noredirect=1#comment636042_374812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed and will go out in the next build. Thanks for finding this one!